# jquery ajax get download file

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

```
$.get(
url: downloadUrl,
function(data) {

//after get the data, how to ask browser pop up to save file?
}
);
```

data is content dumped by server side servlet. can be binary

Comment: Does this have to be done in AJAX rather than just linking to the file?

Comment: the purpose of doing ajax get is need to put some custom header before do get

Comment: Hi, can you please explain how you fixed this.. ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use Ajax for this, just `location = downloadUrl;`

Comment: ya, i know . the purpose of doing ajax get is need to put some custom header before do get